# Memory efficient datastructure for hashmap (c++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, hashmap

The scenario is a kind of simple.

I get a value, in range between `0 and 2^x (x~27)`. Now i would like to use this value also as key for a hashmap. In the hashmap I then just store an index (source of the value). x may be also greater then 27, so I have to use a memory efficient data structure.
I first tried an unordered_multimap, but there is a big overhead, disqualifying it. Then i tried an unordered_map of vectors. But by increasing number of vectors in the map, the overhead is also too big. So I thought of just using a 2d Array with reallocating for dynamic size.
But as I learned here on stackoverflow calling 2^27 times "malloc()" creates also an overhead, so i tried this:

```
uint64_t length = (uint64_t) pow(2.0,27);
uint64_t ** hashmap;
hashmap = (uint64_t **) malloc(sizeof * hashmap * length);
uint64_t * values = (uint64_t *) malloc(sizeof * values * 3 * length);


for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    hashmap[i] = values + 3 * i;

//Destroys the whole datastructure
hashmap[0] = (uint64_t *) realloc(hashmap[0],sizeof*hashmap[0]*4);
```

I allocate `3 * siezof * values` to keep track of actual length and maximal length of the bucket. 
But as the comment says the reallocating destroys the whole arrray, maybe because there is no bookkeeping (via malloc) on the pointer  that it just stores 3 elements?
Is there a way to do a realloc on this structure? Or do u even know a better structure for my intend?

Edit cause of dau_sama's Answer:

While using the following Code, I'm excpierencing performance problems (runtime and memory):

```
std::unordered_map <uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>> m;
uint64_t length = 1UL<<22;
for(int i = 0 ; i<length;i++)
{
    m.emplace(i,vector<uint64_t>());
    m.at(i).push_back(i);
}
```

I reduced the length to 2^22 cause i aborted the 2^27 implementation at a runtime of 7 Minutes and a memory usage of ~8GB. 
This snippet has a runtime of 60 seconds and a memory usage of ~1.7GB. Compared to the above array implementation that's alot, array took ~4GB of memory and a runtime of 1.7 seconds (at 2^27 elements). Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What are your lookup/modification patterns? If i only had lookup and no modification and `std::unordered_map<int, int>` has too much management overhead, I'd stick with a sorted vector of int-int-pairs and use `std::binary_search()`.

Comment: Please compute 2^27 using `1UL << 27`, not floating point.  It's better in every aspect.

Comment: @dhke After the Hashmap is created, i just need to find collisions, so i get a new value in the same range and have to find all equivalent values in the hashmap. No modification / deletion needed.

Comment: If you allocate a vector for every(!!!) one of the 2^27 possible input values, then that is not a hashmap and it doesn't provide any of its benefits (well, it  could pass as degenerate hashmap like a linked list can pass as a tree structure). Then, you allocate storage for every possible bucket without even storing any data in it. Sorry, but you haven't grokked your own data structure yet. This should make you think, because it could also mean that the overhead you try to avoid is just as much based on a flawed assumption. Use a sorted vector, as dhke suggested!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, you are right, the creation of the vectors by not knowing, if it's needed is an unnecessary overhead. Could u explain the sorted vector approach in more detail?

Comment: Think of it as a table, where the first column is the value (duplicates possible) and the second column is the index it came from. The most terse data structure for that is a `std::vector<pair<int, int>>`, because only one dynamic allocation takes place. For every input value, you add one row (i.e. one `pair<int,int>`) to that table. Once done, you sort it by the first column. For lookup, you then use a simple binary search.

Comment: ... plus the nice effect that duplicate values in that sorted table are contiguous. Thus if you iterative through the entries, any two or more subsequent elements with the same key are duplicates.

Comment: thanks for explanation. But I'm loosing the log(N) factor for sorting. So the sorting of a list with 2^27 Elements needs ~2^32 operations... could be a runtime problem. But I will try this approach.

Answer (score -1):

it's as simple as:
don't reinvent the wheel, have a `std::unordered_map<int, int>` that maps what you need. It's nice that you understand pointers, but you don't actually need to call `malloc` directly most of the cases.

Comment: The Problem at this is, that i can just store one value for one key, but i need the possiblity to store more then one, cause values can appear twice or more often.

Comment: and why can't you use a `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>` in this case? what kind of performance problems are you encountering? just saying: it has a big overhead doesn't really mean anything.